# Beta regression (betareg) with caret and train

Tags: r, caret, stepwise-regression, beta-regression

I have a dataset with a dependent in range (0,1) and numerical/categorical predictors. Chiefly to streamline the code and easily accomplish cross validation (feature selection/model fitting), I would like to use `betareg` with `caret`. I thought the model components would be something like:

```
library <- "betareg"
type <- "Regression"
loop <- NULL
fit <- betareg.fit(x, y, z = NULL, weights = NULL, offset = NULL,
                  link = "logit", link.phi = "log", type = "ML", 
                  control = betareg.control())
predict <- predict(object, newdata = NULL,
                   type = c("response", 
                            "link", "precision", "variance", "quantile"),
                   na.action = na.pass, at = 0.5)
```

`parameters` and `grid` don't seem to be relevant in this case? How off am I?

On a different note, would it be possible to do stepwise beta regression (ideally with caret)?

Comment: You would have to write a custom model method. There is a [help page](https://topepo.github.io/caret/using-your-own-model-in-train.html) for doing that.

Answer (score 3):

Bit late to the party on this one, but kept coming back to this page when I was having problems creating the custom betareg model in caret, so I thought I would share my code for anyone else who might have the same problems while following the caret help page.

Firstly, I couldn't get the fit function to recognize `param$type, param$link` etc, as expand.grid converts strings to factors by default. Secondly, I couldn't get the fit to work following the help page, so I looked at some examples of models in the caret github repo, mainly looking at the `glm.R` code. Thirdly, I had to add `if(!is.data.frame(newdata)) newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata)` to the predict function, which I also gathered from the `glm.R` code.

Anyway here is the full reproducible code (welcome any suggestions to make it better):

```
# betareg caret
library(caret)
library(betareg)

# create a betareg caret model
# type and library
betaregression <- list(type='Regression', 
                       library='betareg',
                       loop=NULL)

# parameters to tune
prm <- data.frame(parameter=c("link", "type", "link.phi"),
                  class= rep("character", 3))

# add to the model
betaregression$parameters <- prm

# grid search, this is the default grid search, user can specify otherwise
# creates 54 separate models, so if looking to speed up try fewer params in grid
betaGrid  <- function(x, y, len=NULL, search="grid"){
  if(search == "grid"){
    out <- expand.grid(link=c("logit", "probit", "cloglog", "cauchit", "log", "loglog"),
                       type=c("ML", "BC", "BR"),
                       link.phi=c("identity", "log", "sqrt"), stringsAsFactors = F) # here force the strings as character,
                                                                                   # othewise get error that the model arguments
                                                                                   # were expecting 'chr' when fitting
  }
  out
}

# add the grid search
betaregression$grid <- betaGrid

# create the fit
betaFit <- function(x, y, wts, param, lev, last, weights, classProbs, ...){

  dat <- if(is.data.frame(x)) x else as.data.frame(x)
  dat$.outcome <- y

  theDots <- list(...)

  modelArgs <- c(list(formula = as.formula(".outcome ~ ."), data = dat, link=param$link, type=param$type), theDots)

  out <- do.call(betareg::betareg, modelArgs)
  out$call <- NULL
  out
}

# betaregression fit
betaregression$fit <- betaFit

# predict element
betaPred <- function(modelFit, newdata, preProc=NULL, submodels=NULL){
  if(!is.data.frame(newdata)) newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata)
  betareg::predict(modelFit, newdata)
}

# add the predict method
betaregression$predict <- betaPred

# regression, no probabities calculated
# just assigning NULL didnt work for some reason
# wrapped in a function instead
betaProb <- function(){
  return(NULL)
}
betaregression$prob <- betaProb


# test it on a dataset
data('GasolineYield', package = 'betareg')

# 10 fold cross validation
fitControl <- trainControl(method='repeatedcv', number = 10, repeats = 5)

# betaregression, takes a min or so with full grid
betareg <- train(yield~batch + temp, data=GasolineYield, method=betaregression,
                 trControl = fitControl) 

# look at output
betareg

32 samples
 2 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 5 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 28, 30, 29, 29, 28, 29, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  link     type  link.phi  RMSE        Rsquared   MAE       
  cauchit  BC    identity  0.05492622  0.9234583  0.04550079
  cauchit  BC    log       0.05492622  0.9234583  0.04550079
  cauchit  BC    sqrt      0.05492622  0.9234583  0.04550079
  cauchit  BR    identity  0.05403391  0.9264029  0.04465883
  cauchit  BR    log       0.05403391  0.9264029  0.04465883
  cauchit  BR    sqrt      0.05403391  0.9264029  0.04465883
  cauchit  ML    identity  0.05630303  0.9178326  0.04659214
  cauchit  ML    log       0.05630303  0.9178326  0.04659214
  cauchit  ML    sqrt      0.05630303  0.9178326  0.04659214
  cloglog  BC    identity  0.03032979  0.9694579  0.02597585
  cloglog  BC    log       0.03032979  0.9694579  0.02597585
  cloglog  BC    sqrt      0.03032979  0.9694579  0.02597585
  cloglog  BR    identity  0.03020959  0.9696479  0.02590309
  cloglog  BR    log       0.03020959  0.9696479  0.02590309
  cloglog  BR    sqrt      0.03020959  0.9696479  0.02590309
  cloglog  ML    identity  0.03049690  0.9692041  0.02607832
  cloglog  ML    log       0.03049690  0.9692041  0.02607832
  cloglog  ML    sqrt      0.03049690  0.9692041  0.02607832
  log      BC    identity  0.03831064  0.9563594  0.03167524
  log      BC    log       0.03831064  0.9563594  0.03167524
  log      BC    sqrt      0.03831064  0.9563594  0.03167524
  log      BR    identity  0.03812148  0.9567147  0.03154570
  log      BR    log       0.03812148  0.9567147  0.03154570
  log      BR    sqrt      0.03812148  0.9567147  0.03154570
  log      ML    identity  0.03857773  0.9558736  0.03185336
  log      ML    log       0.03857773  0.9558736  0.03185336
  log      ML    sqrt      0.03857773  0.9558736  0.03185336
  logit    BC    identity  0.02522086  0.9772074  0.02177468
  logit    BC    log       0.02522086  0.9772074  0.02177468
  logit    BC    sqrt      0.02522086  0.9772074  0.02177468
  logit    BR    identity  0.02515359  0.9772928  0.02172167
  logit    BR    log       0.02515359  0.9772928  0.02172167
  logit    BR    sqrt      0.02515359  0.9772928  0.02172167
  logit    ML    identity  0.02531989  0.9770881  0.02184505
  logit    ML    log       0.02531989  0.9770881  0.02184505
  logit    ML    sqrt      0.02531989  0.9770881  0.02184505
  loglog   BC    identity  0.01738742  0.9841774  0.01522962
  loglog   BC    log       0.01738742  0.9841774  0.01522962
  loglog   BC    sqrt      0.01738742  0.9841774  0.01522962
  loglog   BR    identity  0.01738068  0.9841642  0.01521700
  loglog   BR    log       0.01738068  0.9841642  0.01521700
  loglog   BR    sqrt      0.01738068  0.9841642  0.01521700
  loglog   ML    identity  0.01739855  0.9841897  0.01524814
  loglog   ML    log       0.01739855  0.9841897  0.01524814
  loglog   ML    sqrt      0.01739855  0.9841897  0.01524814
  probit   BC    identity  0.02160624  0.9821469  0.01865252
  probit   BC    log       0.02160624  0.9821469  0.01865252
  probit   BC    sqrt      0.02160624  0.9821469  0.01865252
  probit   BR    identity  0.02157626  0.9821566  0.01862963
  probit   BR    log       0.02157626  0.9821566  0.01862963
  probit   BR    sqrt      0.02157626  0.9821566  0.01862963
  probit   ML    identity  0.02165169  0.9821278  0.01869135
  probit   ML    log       0.02165169  0.9821278  0.01869135
  probit   ML    sqrt      0.02165169  0.9821278  0.01869135

RMSE was used to select the optimal model using the smallest value.
The final values used for the model were link = loglog, type = BR and link.phi = identity.
```